# Mounting problems with autofs and executable maps

Tags: catalina, script, automount, autofs

I wanted to replace my already existing and working autofs mount to my NAS with a script variant, which additionally wakes up the server via WoL if necessary and requests the password via keychain. According to Apple's Autofs whitepaper this should be possible via executable maps.

The previous working static file /etc/auto_nas looks like this:

```
video       -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw   ://user:password@192.168.99.99/video
music       -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw   ://user:password@192.168.99.99/music
photo       -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw   ://user:password@192.168.99.99/photo
```

The new script itself works as it should and can also be executed as root (700). It prints the same content as the old auto_nas.

```
#!/bin/bash 

SERVERIP="192.168.99.99"
SERVERMAC="00:00:00:00:00:00"
SERVERUSER="user"
WAITTIME="80"

get_pw () {
  security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-internet-password -ga $SERVERUSER \
  |ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: "(.*)"$/')
}

ping -c 1 -W 1 -q $SERVERIP > /dev/null
status=$?
logger "AUTOFS: Result from ping - $status"
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
then
        logger "AUTOFS: Host is not up. Sending wake-on-lan"
        wakeonlan $SERVERMAC
        logger "AUTOFS: Sleeping for $WAITTIME seconds to allow host to wake"
        sleep $WAITTIME
fi

logger "AUTOFS: Re-pinging host"
ping -c 1 -W 1 -q $SERVERIP > /dev/null
status=$?
logger "AUTOFS: Result - $status"

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then
        logger "AUTOFS: Mounting filesystem"

        echo -e \
"video\t\t-fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw\t://"$SERVERUSER":"$(get_pw)"@$SERVERIP/video\n\
photo\t\t-fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw\t://"$SERVERUSER":"$(get_pw)"@$SERVERIP/photo\n\
music\t\t-fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw\t://"$SERVERUSER":"$(get_pw)"@$SERVERIP/music\n\

else
logger "AUTOFS: Still no ping result from host"
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "DiskStation cannot be woken up"''
fi
```

But if I put the script into /etc/auto_master with

```
/DiskStation auto_nas
```

the DiskStation folder will remain empty and be recognized as a share itself according to the folder icon.

What could be the reason?

```
sudo automount -vc
```

does not display any further log information or errors. Is there any way to extend the log output? `-v` should supposed to be verbose mode.

Update:
It seems that Automount first runs the script without any arguments and then the script has to output only the local mount paths (keys). When called with one of the keys, it must then output the appropriate path to the server and mount options if necessary. Nevertheless, it still does not work with that. I also found different statements how exactly the keys have to be printed. In some examples the complete server path is already printed without any arguments together with the keys.